# Set up Raspberry Pi 3 USB mic ( creative sound blaster )

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi3, soundcard

Can someone please help me in setting up my RPi 3. I'm tying to build a speech to text / speech recognition with my gaming headset (Creative Technology, Ltd Sound Blaster Tactic(3D) Sigma sound card). The speakers are now working but unfortunately I'm stuck in setting up the mic.

Before i tweaked the settings, I can record/create a wav file but whenever i play the wav file there's no sound. After changing some settings, i'm encountering new error below. Thanks in advance!

**Error:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -D plughw:0,0 test9.wav
Recording WAVE 'test9.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
arecord: pcm_read:2031: read error: Interrupted system call
```

**Configs:**

~/.asoundrc

```
pcm.!default { type plug slave { pcm "hw:0,0" } }
ctl.!default { type hw card 0 }
```

/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.pcm.subdevice -1
```

/lib/modprobe.d/aliases.conf

```
options snd-pcsp index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2

# Does the reordering.
options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-bcm2835
```

aplay -l

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Sigma [Sound Blaster Tactic(3D) Sigma], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord -l

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Sigma [Sound Blaster Tactic(3D) Sigma], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I have managed to fix the problem! It turns out that when I run alsamixer, the `~/.asoundrc` config file automatically updates. My config were overwritten by the new settings.